# Eclipse: Source Not found, Find the source, then switches back

Tags: java, eclipse

I keep getting the "Source not found message".  I added the source from the file system.  It finds the source for a few seconds, then the window switches back.  It's only for one project.  If I try to find the Java project, it's not found.

Comment: Are you using any plugins that will change your .project for you?  (e.g. some of the Maven plugins)

Comment: @Tim, yes, I'm using a Maven plugin.  I haven't been able to recreate this since setting everything up again in Eclipse/Maven.

Comment: Glad you got it working.